# Discrete random variables. Independence

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Discrete random variables $X1, X2, X3$ are independent and have the same distribution
[image]

Let  $Y = max (X1; X2; X3).$  Find the distribution Y.

If i understood correctly, the task is: find the maximum value between $X1,X2,X3$ and then create new table and start calculating the probability of one of the $X1 ,X2 or X3.$ But I'm not sure in my opinion. Could you please explain, what is the main idea of the task and  this expression $Y = max {X1; X2; X3}.$?

Comment: You have 5 options for the max: 1,2,3,4,5. For example, $Y=1$ iff all the RVs are 1, which happens with probability $0.2^3$. Now complete the other cases.

Comment: Could you explain, please, what is RVs and why the probability of RVs is equal to $0,2^3$ ?

Comment: RV=random variables. For the maximum of 3 numbers in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to be $1$, all of them must be $1$, and this is the probability of this event.

Comment: We have not said that a maximum of 3 numbers from  $(1,2,3,4,5)$  should be equal to 1. Where are these judgments from?

Comment: It is not a judgment but merely an event that might occur and you should find its probability to occur. @YJT explained how to do that and encouraged you to the same for other events (like e.g. $Y=3$). Doing so you are creating a table for $Y$ (comparable with the one for $X_k$ in your question). That is exactly what you are asked to do ("find the distribution of $Y$").

Comment: @drhab Could I say that for $Y=2,P=0,048 and Y=3,P=0,925$ ?

Comment: No, it is beyond doubt that you made mistakes. You must realize that for $k=2,3,4,5$ the event $\{Y=k\}$ is the same as the event $\{Y\leq k\}-\{Y\leq k-1\}$. Consequence of that is the equality: $$P(Y=k)=P(Y\leq k)-P(Y\leq k-1)$$Here $P(Y\leq k)$ is not difficult to find because: $$Y\leq k\iff X_i\leq k\text{ for }i=1,2,3$$

Comment: @drhab Got it, then it turns out $Y=2,P(Y=2)=1$ and $Y=3, P(Y=3)=1$ and the table will look like                                                                                                                                 $Y 1 2 3 $                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                      
$P 1 1 1 $   ?

Comment: No, that is not what it turns. For e.g. $P(Y=2)$ we find $P(Y\leq2)-P(Y\leq1)=0.4^3-0.2^3$.

Comment: @drhab Understood, can you please tell me where you can read the information for a more delicate acquaintance with the solution

Comment: I am afraid not. What you learned now must land. That's all. Think it over several times and it will. Cheers.